# How to I change an n-by-n matrix to a point cloud matrix?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, coordinates, point-clouds

I have a 1265x1777 matrix with the intensity values of an image. I need to develop a point cloud file in MATLAB for the same. Just like a 3D scatter where x, y and z coordinates are stored in a variable; x, y should represent the pixel location; and z corresponds to the intensity of that pixel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Updated according to OP's comment.

Assuming your 1265x1777 matrix is called 'img':

```
x = 1:size(img,2);
y = 1:size(img,1);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);

xyz_matrix = [X(:), Y(:), img(:)];
```

Comment: Hi Jakob, I need a matrix having 3 columns having x coordinates in the first column and y coordinates in the second column and the intensity values of the corresponding pixel in the third column. For example if intensity matrix is [1 2 3; 4 5 6] then the output matrix i need will something looks like this[1 1 1; 1 2 2;1 3 3; 2 1 4; 2 2 5; 2 3 6]. Thanks

Comment: Updated my answer.